# Restringir acesso a rotas caso não esteja logado Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou desenvolvendo um `Dashboard` e me veio a duvida de como proibir que acessem as `rotas` se não estiverem `logados`, com isso, pensei em algumas soluções que usuariam `localStorage`, mas, nenhuma é uma solução certa.

Qual seria a maneira correta de fazer isso? vi que muitas pessoas possuem essa duvida, e não consegui uma solução para isso.

Comment: Você está usando o vue-router?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, estou usando `Vue-Router`

Comment: Não vou conseguir escrever uma resposta agora, mas veja a documentação do vue-router. Ele permite interceptar a rota antes de navegar pra ela. Nesse momento você tem de consultar o servidor sobre permissões de acesso, e só liberar a rota se a resposta for positiva. Isso vai gerar um "loading" entre as rotas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aqueles que mesmo com a documentação tiveram a mesma dificuldade do que eu para implementar, segue o codigo e uma breve explicação.

No meu `main.js` eu defini globalmente

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(to)
    if(to.name == 'Dashboard'){
        alert('dashboard')
    }else{
        next()
    }

})
```

Com isso, já é possivel restringir o acesso sem a permissão (eu não fiz nenhuma validação nesse exemplo), porem, ao tentar acessar via `URL` ainda assim é possivel, porem, consegui resolver com o seguinte codigo na minha pagina `Dashboard`

```
<script>
    export default{
        beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
            if(to.meta.adminOnly === true){
                next('/')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Com isso, bastaria verficar se o usuario está logado, caso não estivesse, ele iria manda-lo novamente para a pagina de login `/`.